# drop database having exclamation and backtick

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to drop a database having special characters (!`) in it.

```
MySQL [test]> show databases;
+-------------------------+
| Database                |
+-------------------------+
| d1                      |
| d2                      |
| db1`; select 'oops!'    |
```

```
MySQL [test]> drop database `db1\`\; select \'oops!\'`;
ERROR: Unknown command '\;'.
ERROR: Unknown command '\''.
ERROR: Unknown command '\''.
    `> Ctrl-C -- exit!
Aborted
MySQL [test]> drop database "db1`; select 'oops!'";
ERROR 1064 (HY000): [33792] syntax error: syntax error near ""db1`; select 'oops!'""
LINE: drop database "db1`; select 'oops!'"
                    ^
```

I tried escaping these characters but it is not deleting for me. Including double quotes throws syntax error. I tried MySQL 5.6/5.7.

Answer (score 3):

To escape a backtick, you need to double it (see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html)). The other characters shouldn't need escaping:

```
DROP DATABASE `db1``; select 'oops!'`
```

If you can control `SQL_MODE`, you can set `ANSI_QUOTES` and surround the string in double quotes:

```
SET SQL_MODE = 'ANSI_QUOTES';
DROP DATABASE "db1`; select 'oops!'"
```

Comment: One more observation:
mysql>  set sql_mode = 'ANSI_QUOTES';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> create database "db11`; select 'oops!'";
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> drop database "db11`; select 'oops!'";
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Comment: @AnuragKumar indeed that will work. People don't always have control over SQL Mode which is why I didn't suggest it; but I will add it to the answer for completeness

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
drop database Database_name;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - are you sure this works when the database name contains any special characters?

Comment: this will not work for my problem. Many special characters we need to escape using escape characters.